# Using a variable (such as t) to label a graph axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I currently have a graph with no numbers on the axis and I wish to have '0' and 't' on the x axis where '3' and '11' should be, thanks in advance. Current graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=1:11, xmin=0, xmax=15, no marks, samples=100, xlabel=time $t$, ylabel=space $x$]
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\addplot {sqrt(x)+sin(\x r/2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The gist of the linked answer is that you can set `xtick={3,11}, xticklabels={0, $t$}` in the `axis` options.